# A question on the Euler polynomials of negative degree

Tags: number-theory

I was reading up on the Euler polynomials and was wondering if there were any way to extend the definition  of the polynomials $E_{n}(X)$ to n less than zero.

Reason I'm asking is because I was playing around with an infinite series of the polynomials and I decided to find an expression for differentiating it some arbitrary number of times. However it requires me to use polynomials with n less than zero.

Btw I have no idea what tag this is under so for now I'm just using number theory.

Comment: From the property $E_n(x+1)+E_n(x)=2x^n$, you can suspect that such a generalization needs to have terms of a negative degree. Once $E_{-1}(x)$ is available, you can use $nE_{n-1}(x)=dE_n(x)/dx$.

Comment: @Yves_Daoust Indeed in theory I could but every single expression I find doesn't allow me to do so. Since you say it can be done perhaps you could provide me an expression for them or at least the first negative degree polynomial

Comment: "you say it can be done": no, I didn't say that. (In the first place I meant it can't be done with a polynomial.)

Comment: @Yvet_Daoust I see sorry for the misunderstanding. But is there an expression for negative degrees, perhaps an infinite series of integral?

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea. The only potentially usable property I found is that recurrence on $n$ via the derivative, but it breaks at $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is that $E_n(x)=0$ if $n<0$ was my guess, but the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.16) claims in section $2.16(iii)$ that "other generalizations include: ... Euler numbers and polynomials with arbitrary complex index (Butzer et al. (1994))", so if you want you can try looking at the reference for details.

P.L. Butzer, S. Flocke and M. Hauss (1994) *Euler functions* $E_\alpha(z)$ *with complex* $\alpha$ *and applications*. In Approximation, probability, and related fields (Santa Barbara, CA, 1993). G. Anastassiou and S. T. Rachev (Eds.), pp. 127–150.

Comment: @Yves_Daoust I found a relation that I think solves it. $$E_{n}(x)=\frac{2}{n+1}(B_{n+1}(x)-2^{n+1}B_{n+1}(x))$$ then using the relation between the Hurwitz zeta and Bernoulli polynomials to extend the definition to negative degrees.

Comment: @Horus Okay, what is $E_{-1}(x)$?

Comment: Apparently equal to $$2\psi(x)-2\psi(\frac{x}{2})$$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function

Comment: There's a typo in the first comment. The relation is supposed to be $$E_{n}(x)=\frac{2}{n+1}(B_{n+1}(x)-2^{n+1}B_{n+1}(\frac{x}{2}))$$